# A matrix is diagonalizable iff it admits the maximum number of linearly independent eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Suppose that $A$ is a square matrix of size $n\times n$. I want to show that $A$ is diagonalizable if only if it admits $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. By definition, $A$ is called diagonalizable if it’s similar to a diagonal matrix, that is, there exists an invertible matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ with $A=P^{-1}DP$

My proof goes as follows. If $A$ is diagonalizable, there exists a diagonal matrix $D$ and an ordered basis of $\mathbb F^n$ such that $D$ is the matrix of the linear map $f_A(x):=Ax$ with respect to the new basis. Hence, this basis gives the collection of $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. The converse follows from a similar “change of basis” argument. Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is fine, but it is not a very clear way of putting it, in my view.

If $A=P^{-1}DP$ with $D$ diagonal, using $\{e_k\}$ for the canonical basis we have that $De_k=d_{kk}e_{k}$. Now it is automatic to check that $\{P^{-1}e_k\}$ are a basis (because $P^{-1}$ is invertible) of eigenvectors for $A$.

Conversely, if $\{v_k\}$ is a basic of eigenvectors for $A$, with corresponding eigenvalues $\{d_k\}$ and $P$ is the matrix with $Pv_k=e_k$, letting $D$ be the diagonal matrix with diagonal $\{d_k\}$ we have
$$
APe_k=Av_k=d_kv_k=d_kPe_k=P(d_ke_k)=PDe_k.
$$
As the $\{e_k\}$ are a basis, $AP=PD$, and since $D$ is invertible, $A=PDP^{-1}$ (I always get the $P$ and $P^{-1}$ on the wrong side on these computations, but it is just a matter of names).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer

Comment: My pleasure. To complement on what I said, arguments like your second paragraph are often fine. But I personally find that sometimes it is also the case that I find such a paragraph  believable, but it ends up being not true. That's why I have a tendency (and suggest doing so) to express things with a little more detail.

Comment: You’re completely right. Nevertheless I tend to go for brevity, so I hope I won’t become an author of math books in the future :D